# Core data error when inserting row into a different segment

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have a table with two segments for morning and evening classes. I am fetching the data for morning and evening classes and appending them to following variables

```
   var morClasses = [String]()
   var eveClasses = [String]()
```

Then, I am displaying them as follows,

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        var partOfDay = 0
        switch (segView.selectedSegmentIndex)
        {
        case 0:
            partOfDay = morClasses.count
            break
        case 1:
            partOfDay = eveClasses.count
            break
        default:break
        }
        return partOfDay
    }


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let cell1 = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "tableViewCell") as! TableViewCell
    let cell2 = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "tableViewCellEve") as! TableViewCellEve

    switch (segView.selectedSegmentIndex)
    {
    case 0:
        cell1.label?.text  = morClasses[indexPath.row]

    case 1:
        cell2.label?.text  = eveClasses[indexPath.row]
        return cell2
    default: break
    }
    return cell1
    }
```

I am inserting them using FRC as follows,

```
func controller(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>, didChange anObject: Any, at indexPath: IndexPath?, for type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: IndexPath?) {
case NSFetchedResultsChangeType.insert:

    var indexPathToInsert = IndexPath(row: newIndexPath!.row, section: 0)
    let classDetailInsert  = fetchedResultsController.object(at: indexPathToInsert) as! ClassDetail
    let numbers = classDetailInsert.dayPart
    let containsMor = numbers!.contains(where: { $0 == 0 })
    let containsEve = numbers!.contains(where: { $0 == 1 })

    var rowToInsert = 0
    var rowToInsertEve = 0

    if (containsMor == true)
    {
        //if-else condition because count is updating N-1 late
        if (morClasses.count >= 1)
        {
            rowToInsert = morClasses.count
        }
        else
        {
            rowToInsert = 0
        }
        indexPathToInsert = IndexPath(row:rowToInsert, section: 0)
        morClasses.insert(classDetailInsert.title!, at: indexPathToInsert.row)
    }

    if (containsEve == true)
    {
        if (eveClasses.count >= 1)
        {
            rowToInsertEve = eveClasses.count
        }
        else
        {
            rowToInsertEve = 0
        }
        indexPathToInsert = IndexPath(row:rowToInsertEve, section: 0)
        eveClasses.insert(classDetailInsert.title!, at: indexPathToInsert.row)
    }
    self.tableView.insertRows(at: [indexPathToInsert], with: .fade)
```

Everything works fine, as long as I am inserting data in one segment, but if I add data pertaining to another segment, I get the following error. That is I can keep on adding morning classes without any error but once I add the evening classes, I get the following error.

> CoreData: fault: Serious application error.  An exception was caught
>   from the delegate of NSFetchedResultsController during a call to
>   -controllerDidChangeContent:.  Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section
>   after the update (1) must be equal to the number of rows contained in
>   that section before the update (1), plus or minus the number of rows
>   inserted or deleted from that section (1 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus
>   or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved
>   in, 0 moved out). with userInfo (null)

I don't know where I am messing up, any help in the direction would be appreciated.

Comment: The code cannot work. Don't misuse `controller:didChange` to manipulate the data source array. And why are you using `NSFetchedResultsController` at all as you don't take advantage of it? Fetch the data with an appropriate predicate and sort descriptor and the fetched results controller does the rest for you. And use the `NSMagagedObject` instances as data source type, not just strings

Comment: Sorry, I don't know about that. So, you mean to say that numberOfRowsInSection and cellForRowAtIndexPath should use appropriate predicate and sort descriptor?

Comment: No, the fetched result controller is supposed to manage everything. When the index of the segmented control changes, assign the predicate (numbers == 0 or numbers == 1) to the fetched result controller and refetch the data. In `numberOfRowsInSection ` return always `fetchedResultsController.sections![section].numberOfObjects`

Comment: @vadian, Appreciate your explanation. So, I think I am getting the idea, so I believe, I have to create an NSManagedObject at cellForRow,looks like array of strings wont work there as well? In that case, I don't have to use two tableview cells?

Comment: Actually you don't even need a data source array, just get everything from the `NSFetchedResultsController` and no switches in `numberOfRowsInSection` and `cellForRowAt`.

Comment: So, instead of switches, I should use if-else with predicates  (numbers == 0 or numbers == 1), as you mentioned above?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194361/discussion-between-coder221-and-vadian).

Comment: No, in the `IBAction` of the `UISegmentedControl` change the predicate depending on the segment, then refetch the data and reload the table view. That's all